# jQuery Modal Window that changes size on loading new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm beginning out with jQuery and I need a modal window that contains a review form. After submitting the form using AJAX, the server will return a status message to be displayed on the modal window. How can I make the modal window be resized (from the large window to hold the review form to a small one that just fits the status message)?

Any recommended plugins/tutorials on this? Is using a plugin the best way to start off?

Comment: I'd check out http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ - it's a fantastic modal solution and has dynamic resizing. The demo's show the resizing with photos in the slideshow, and it supports both AJAX and iFrame solutions. It shouldn't be difficult to tap into that resize method on an ajax `success:function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try jQuery ui dialog with "width" and "height" properties set to "auto"

Answer (score 2):

One caveat of setting `width` and `height` to `auto` is that when the dialog is larger in size than your content underneath, it will stretch. I found setting the `maxHeight` and/or `maxWidth` helpful in controlling that. One problem with `maxHeight` though is that, it sometimes doesn't work! Luckily, there is a simple workaround:

```
$(".dialog").dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({'max-height': 400, 'overflow-y': 'auto'}); 
    },
    ...
});
```